# Installing multiple packages with composer?

Tags: zend-framework, composer-php

I am trying to install the latest version of `Zend Framework 2` with composer and also install at least one other package at the same time. The other package is another `Zend Framework` package. The two packages are:
`zendframework/zendframework`
`zendframework/zendservice-twitter`

I added `zendframework/zendservice-twitter` to the require section of that file. It doesn't look like there is any other section to use to install multiple packages in the same directory tree. But when I try to add `zendframework/zendservice-twitter` to the require section of the `composer.json` file, it tells me that `zendframework/zend-uri` is required. But `zendframework/zend-uri` is installed by the `zendframework/zendframework` package. It is listed in the replace section of that `composer.json` file. So apparently the replace section is not the place to add other packages that need to be installed. But you can't have multiple composer.json files in the same directory either, so is it even possible to install `Zend Framework 2` and `ZendServiceTwitter` in the same installation with composer?

When I download a package as a zip file from https://packages.zendframework.com/#composer, I get a composer.json file in the zip file, but it does not have the same repository setting that it says to use at https://packages.zendframework.com. So I am not sure if that composer.json file is intended to be edited in order to upgrade or reinstall.

Isn't there some way to tell composer that this is a circular dependency?

Comment: Can you please add the composer.json file of your project to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the circular dependency. The twitter package requires `zend-uri`, and `zend-uri` is provided by the main Zend Framework package that you've already installed.

I just tried this out on a fresh checkout of the skeleton app and it worked fine. All I did was add the twitter package to the `require` section of my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
    "zendframework/zendservice-twitter": "~2.1.0"
}
```

(2.1.0 is the latest version of it at the moment.) You don't need to touch the `replace` section.

Comment: I am only installing Zend Framework and the Twitter service for now, so I have zendframework/zendframework in the name section and zendframework/zendservice-twitter in the require section.

Comment: Both should be in the `require` section as in my example. `name` is for the name of your project.